# Which HTTP status code to return when entity already processed

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

I have an API endpoint that anonymises a customer's personal data.

`https://shop.dev/gdpr/customer/anonymize?id=123`

If a customer cannot be found, you return a 404.
If validation fails, you send a 400.

What would be the correct status code to return if a customer is already anonymised and the action should not be processed?

Comment: Would a 409 - Conflict make sense in this case?

Comment: The `anonymize` "resource" sounds a bit RPC to me. Is it really worth an own resource? Also, why not simply return 200 OK and just ignore the task if the data was already anonymized. I'd also use an update (either via PUT or PATCH) of the state instead where the client would send the new values he wants to see replaced. Here the client is in control of what data has to be anonymized in contrast with your approach where this is somekind of a blackbox and may require internal knowledge of the client.

Comment: @RomanVottner RPC as in RPC vs RESTful?

Comment: Some people consider verbs in URLs bad practice as the verb is used already in the HTTP operation, though as the URI should not be interpreted this is just a minor detail. The core essence though is, that you try to invoke some business logic on the server by invoking a simple URI. This is similar to how SOAP works. REST however builds around resources. The anonymized data can thus be provided by clients themselfs on updating the existing state with the one they want to see after the operation was performed.